# Device Location Verification

Tags: android, ios, location

How would I verify/ track device location within a 5' accuracy?  I've heard of people using cell towers/ gps combinations.

Comment: Both iOS and Android support querying the GPS unit as well as using cell towers to identify location.  What question do you have?

Comment: The documentation for iOS answers your question: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html No idea about Android.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to get a 5 feet accuracy figure is to use GPS, then it still isn't always that accurate depending on how good a fix of the satellites (clear view to the sky) you have.

Cell tower / Wifi triangulation methods only serve to speed up positioning and will seldom (if ever) be more accurate than satellite positioning methods.

Answer (score 0):

GPS is the way to go.  Cell towers won't cut it.  In Android (and I believe iOS) the system will provide you with an accuracy reading in addition to the actual location.  You could use this value to determine whether the value you've received should be uploaded to your server.  Keep in mind using the GPS is very battery intensive and there's no guarantee of how good the accuracy will be.  Depending on conditions you may not be able to achieve 5' precision.

As @CommonsWare points out, 5' is really unrealistic anyway although you can get close.

Comment: 5' (i.e., under 2m) is unrealistic. 10m is doing pretty good for consumer-grade cell-phone GPS receivers.

Comment: @CommonsWare ah you're right, I was thinking 3' not 3m. Really 9' would be a better lower limit

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare says you will not get much better that 10 metters accuracy in a consummer-grade device. Even in open sky, the atmosphere characteristcs change minute by minute and thats enough to change the GPS readings.

However, it's teoreticaly possible to increase accuracy if you could get all of the following:

1-There are some stationary GPS receiver stations with fixed known locations which measure the current GPS signals deviation. You would need to have one of those close to you and have access to the data in real time.

2-You would need to have low level access to your phone GPS receiver to read the unprocessed data received from sattelites. This would be different from device to device, and as far as I know, no supplier is providing this access.

3-Finnaly, you would need to do all the calculations required to determine your location applying the deviations got from point 1 above.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get this type of accuracy is with WAAS. As far as I know, there are no Android handsets that can receive WAAS corrections. If this is for a specific controlled situation, you could use a bluetooth gps receiver with WAAS, and only in WAAS supported locations.  However, if this was for a wider deployment, then I think you are out of luck.